# Cannot resolve GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE

Tags: android, api, google-fit

I am using Google Fit API in Android Studio and I was following the [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started), but an error occurred, saying:

> cannot resolve the symbol.

I have searched for a solution for this, but I could not find one.

I have also put the dependencies on my module gradle, as told in their website.

> GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE

Here is the code I have copied from the above mentioned link:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();
        if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
            GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(this,  GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions);
        } else {

            accessGoogleFit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode ==  GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
                accessGoogleFit();
            }
        }
    }
    private void accessGoogleFit() {
        final  String LOG_TAG="i am here";
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();


        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readData(readRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSuccess()");
                    }


                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onFailure()", e);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onComplete()");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You haven't define it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 123456; //whatever you want
  // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The **requestCode** is part of a Service Callback design pattern.  The way the example is written implies the possibility that your app code somehow receives a callback for a service request that was made by a different client instance.

The test for a matching **requestCode** parameter passed in **onActivityResult()** is a defensive coding guard against an instance of your app code responding to the result of a service request that it did not initiate. Since we are talking about app permissions here, this is a privacy and security concern.  This hypothetical "rouge callback" might be generated by malware on the user device, or a compromised service end-point, or some kind of man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacker on the network.

Unfortunately hard-coding a fixed **requestCode** as is very often done might not provide the best protection against this scenario, since every instance of your class uses the same value.

For a more dynamic value of **requestCode** you could use something like this instead (noting request code is only allowed to use the lowest 16 bits of the integer, so we mask it using the bitwise '&' operator):

```
final int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = System.identityHashCode(this) & 0xFFFF;
```